# Schedule DAGs to process jobs in series

Tags: airflow

I have a list of jobs in db produced by the app. I have a DAG that can process one job. It's a compute intensive DAG whereas I have quite limited resources.

How could I schedule DAGs so they are running one by one in series to ultimately process all jobs?

So far, I have come up with the following solution, but I feel that it does not look idiomatic to Airflow. Guess such task is usually solved with the task-queue services, e.g. Amazon SQS or GCP Cloud Tasks. But what if I need to use airflow only.

```
Each 2 minutes run a "schedule" DAG that:

[check_no_job_is_being_processing -> trigger_processing_dag -> mark_job_as_processed]
```

EDIT 1 ------------------

Thanks for suggestions! I updated the "schedule" DAG. Now, Airflow guarantees that only one "schedule" DAG is running at the time. Solution looks much cleaner with less custom code

```
[take_job -> trigger_processing_dag -> mark_job_as_processed]

with DAG(
  max_active_runs=1,
  schedule_interval='* * * * *'        
) as dag:
```

- `max_active_runs=1` - tells Airflow to run just one "schedule" DAG per time
- `schedule_interval='* * * * *'` - periodically trigger the DAG if none is running

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch of settings you can use to force only one process at a time, but they look like system wide settings rather than for a specific DAG. https://hevodata.com/learn/airflow-parallelism/#:~:text=Airflow%20Parallelism%3A%20Core%20Settings,-The%20number%20of&text=Parallelism%3A%20This%20is%20the%20maximum,run%20concurrently%20across%20all%20DAGs.

Comment: Does your dags has order theyneed to run? If not then you can define a pool that is limited to one dag each time